# Differences between chess engines

Tags: engines, programming

In what way do major chess engines differ from one another?

Do they all use the same algorithm and the same evaluation function, differing only in parameters/weights?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

- I'm confident both Houdini and Komodo are in C/C++, the best language for speed optimization.
- I'd be very surprised if they don't use alpha-beta/nega-max. This is standard in chess programming.
- I don't know about board representation in Houdini and Komodo, but bitboard is good and fast. Stockfish uses that, and I think it's common for all strong engines.

**ORIGINAL**

Lot's of possibilities (I can't list everything):

- **How to prune/reduce the search tree**?
- **How to evaluate a chess position**?
- What about quiescence search? Do you want to extend your search horizon?
- Bitboard? Mailbox? How do you want to represent the internal board?
- Multithreading support?
- Programming language. C++? Java?
- Operating systems optimisations such as large pages?

While all chess engines I'm aware of use alpha-beta/nega-max, their implementation could be significantly different.

No. They **don't** all use the same algorithm and the same evaluation function. Visit https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Home, and you'll appreciate the complexity in chess engine programming.

Comment: Could you give concrete examples for some of the strongest engines (stockfish, Houdini, Komodo,....)? I understand that there are lots of possibilities, but perhaps some of those possibilities are better than others and are therefore preferred in the stronger engines!?

Comment: @user1583209 Komod and Houdini are closed source. Thus, not possible to say anything for their algorithms. We can only get their analysis, but we don't know the details.

Comment: @user1583209 Any concrete example will just give you a different move, different principal variation, different score. But, you'll never know why because no source code for Houdini and Komodo. Is that what you want?

Comment: I had the hope that at least a few things were known about closed source engines. For instance you state that all engines use "alpha-beta/nega-max". How about "bitboards", ....? Probably the strong engines are not written in Java either!?

Comment: @user1583209 I'm not able to find an example. I'll try to find an example if nobody else answers this question.